# Is It Possible to Conditionally Redirect a URL using RedirectMatch?

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following to redirect all pages from an old URL structure to a new one.

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://sitename.com/$3`

The old structure is as follows:
http://sitename.com/2010/09/file-name/

The new structure is as follows:
https://sitename.com/file-name/

The redirect works fine.

My question is: Is it possible to use this redirect along with a condition? I want to exclude all facebook bots from this redirect.

I tried the following, but it is not working:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/[0-9]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://sitename.com/$3`

Is it possible to run a RedirectMatch with a condition? If not, what is the alternative I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedirectMatch is `mod_alias` RrwriteCond is `mod_rewrite` so , you couldn't use it with.

Use `mod_rewrite` only like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/[0-9]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ https://sitename.com/$3 [R=301,L]
```

This `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` condition to match against none `https` only .

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it .

**UPDATE :**

If you want to force all request into `https` and apply rules above as well, do this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/[0-9]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/[0-9]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(?!page/)(.+)$ /$3 [R=301,L]
```

**Again**: clear browser cache then test it .

Comment: Thank you, the code works perfectly. But there is a small issue, I also want to redirect all HTTP urls to HTTPS. Is it possible to incorporate that into this code? Perhaps another line as follows:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: @M.kesh dont use your suggestion , looping will happened but i could give you alternative solution , just wait

Comment: The following are the main types of requests and redirects: 

`1.) http://example.com -> https://example.com
2.) http://example.com/file/ -> https://example.com/file/
3.) http://example.com/0000/00/filename -> https://example.com/filename
4.) https://example.com/0000/00/filename -> https://example.com/filename`

Comment: so , it is better to force them all into https and exclude facebook then redirect any request like 1120/11/file to file right?

Comment: @M.kesh see updated code , i excluded facebook two times because it should not be involved in both rules

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly!